# Theano GPU Install failed nvcc

Tags: python, gpu, theano

After installing Winpython, and launching

```
from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
import theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops
import theano.tensor as T
```

I got this error message:

ValueError: Theano nvcc.flags support only parameter/value pairs without space between them. e.g.: '--machine 64' is not supported, but '--machine=64' is supported. Please add the '=' symbol. nvcc.flags value is 'D:_devs\Python01\WinPython-64\python-3.4.3.amd64\libs'

My theanorc. config file is:

```
[nvcc]
fastmath = True
flags=-LD:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64\python-3.4.3.amd64\libs
compiler_bindir=D:\_app\visualstudio13\VC\bin
```

Has anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Find the issue and correct file syntax:

```
[nvcc]
fastmath = True
--flags=-LD:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64\python-3.4.3.amd64\libs
--compiler_bindir=D:\_app\visualstudio13\VC\bin\
```

Solved.